# Obtain the partial fraction representation of $\pi\cot\pi z$ using an integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, partial-fractions

This is an exercise problem in GTM11 by Conway (chap. V 2.8). It asks me to show

$$\pi\cot\pi a=\frac{1}{a}+\sum_{n\neq0}\left(\frac{1}{a-n}+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

by using the fact that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\gamma_n}\frac{\pi\cot\pi z}{z^2-a^2}dz=0$$

where $\gamma_n$ is the square centered at 0 with side length $2n-1$.

Now I have been able to show the integral goes to 0, but I cannot see how this leads to the partial fraction development of $\pi\cot\pi z$. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Apply residue Theorem to $\int_{\gamma_n} \frac {\pi \cot(\pi z)} {z^{2}-a^{2}}$. The poles are at $\pm a$ and $\pm k$ with $|k|<n$.

Comment: can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Please try it out and show your attempt. Otherwise your question may be voted down and even closed.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I thought the residue theorem was used to obtain that the integral goes to 0. Since I already did that I didn't pay much attention to it. Thanks again.